# What is the meaning of the getcwd() method?

Tags: python, operating-system, getcwd

```
import os 
cwd = os.getcwd()
df.to_csv(cwd+ "/BA_reviews.csv")
```

I didn't understand this code properly. Can someone help?

Answer (score 1):

[`os.getcwd` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.getcwd)

> Return a string representing the current working directory.

so

```
import os 
cwd = os.getcwd()
df.to_csv(cwd+ "/BA_reviews.csv")
```

means read `BA_reviews.csv` from current working directory.

Answer (score 0):

```
import os

# os.getcwd() is a method in os module which gives the current directory
cwd = os.getcwd

# df is dataframe and to_csv is saving the df data in csv file 
#here file name is BA_reviews.csv
# you are basically concaneting the path and the filename 

df.to_csv(cwd+"/BA_reviews.csv")
```

Answer (score 0):

Tha's just getting the absolute path of the current folder in order to save, from the pandas dataframe, a cvs file into that folder. You can either do the same using the built-in library specific for path operations, pathlib, and f-strings, in a more pythonic way:

```
import pathlib

cwd = pathlib.Path().absolute()
df.to_csv(f"{cwd}/BA_reviews.csv")
```